# On highlighting text, highlighting receives border radius

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know how, using CSS/JS, to make it so that the highlight portion when selecting text has border radius, similar to how is done in [Sublime Text](http://media02.hongkiat.com/sublime-text-tips/sorting-css.gif?new02).

Comment: It's fairly easy to do with Rangy: http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/highlighter.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's way to do what you wanted:
From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aselection):

> Only a small subset of CSS properties can be used in a rule using ::selection in its selector: color, background, background-color and text-shadow. Note that, in particular, background-image is ignored, like any other property.

Comment: You can do that with JS. :)